# Determining values of the statements

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, logic

I have a hard time, solving some logical statement exercises. Given two statements $v(x): |x| = 2$ and $u(x): x > 1$, where $x \in A = \{-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$, I have to determine all values of statements, that are constructed from $u(x)$ and $v(x)$. I'm not sure, that my answers are right, because there are no solutions for it.

1. $v(x) = \{2\}$.
2. $u(x) = \{2, 3, 4\}$.
3. $\lnot v(x) \land u(x) = \{-1, 0, 1, 3, 4\} \land \{2, 3, 4\} = \{3, 4\}.$ Is this one right?
4. $\lnot u(x) \implies v(x).$ I don't know how to solve that one, can anybody please help with it?
5. $\lnot v(x) \iff \lnot u(x) = \{-1, 0, 1, 3, 4\} \iff \{-1, 0, 1\} = \{-1, 0, 1\}.$ Is this one right?
6. $\lnot u(x) \lor v(x) = \{-1, 0, 1\} \lor \{2\} = \{-1, 0, 1, 2\}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 3 are correct.

For the 4th, an implication is true exactly when the premise is false, so $u(x)$ holds, so for the set $\{2,3,4\}$, *or* when the conclusion is true, so $v(x) = \{2\}$, but this adds nothing new.

So the implication only holds for $\{2,3,4\}$.

For 5, we take the union of the sets corresponding to $u(x) \land v(x)$ and $\lnot u(x) \land \lnot v(x)$. (Whenever $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ have the same truth value). So this is $\{2\} \cap \{2,3,4\} = \{2\}$, unioned with $\{-1,0,1,3,4\} \cap \{-1,0,1\} = \{-1,0,1\}$. So the total is $\{-1,0,1,2\}$.

6 I agree with.

Comment: Can you please describe why is 4 as is more broadly? I still can't get it. :)

Comment: I just use that $\lnot u(x) \Rightarrow v(x)$ is equivalent to $u(x) \lor v(x)$.

Comment: And 5 is equivalent to $v(x) \Leftrightarrow u(x)$ which is equivalent to $(u(x) \land v(x)) \lor (\lnot u(x) \land \lnot v(x))$

Comment: Oh, I get it, what keywords should I use to get brief idea of those formulas and their deriving?

Comment: It's basic propositional logic.